# Can't enable wayland after upgrade to 22.04.1

Tags: nvidia, xorg, 22.04, wayland

I've just upgraded from 20.04 LTS, to Jammy, but I can't get Wayland available on my machine.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A5v33.png)

I've also edited `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` and enabled Wayland (`WaylandEnable=true`), but it's not showing as an option upon login either.

Also I have the latest Nvidia driver installed:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YwWV.png)

Is this probably a bug? If so is there anymore info needed before I can report it?

Answer (score 1):

See the file `/lib/udev/rules.d/61-gdm.rules` on your system.

Lots of hardware is incompatible with Wayland, and if detected you won't be offered Wayland. It's a feature, not a bug.

If your hardware IS compatible with Wayland after all, then it's a bug.

Comment: I see, whenever I enable nvidia-driver-510 or 515, it switches back to X11, but whenever I use the (open source) option: 

`X.Org X server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau`

Wayland gets enabled on the next restart.

According to the rules file, u mentioned above, Wayland should be compatible with nvidia driver 510 and above.

So how can I identify whether this counts as a bug?